# Start of X-days prior

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

```
time("D",session.regular,syminfo.timezone)
```

This gives me start time of current day. How do I get start of the previous trading day or 2 trading days ago?

if I do the following for SPY, it gives me 01/08's start time (Sunday/non-trading day) instead of 01/06's start time (Friday/trading day)

```
int backDays = 1 // how many days to go back
time("D",session.regular,syminfo.timezone) - (86400000 * backDays)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

var int n = input.int(2, 'Show startTime for this many trading days ago', 0)

var int[] startTimes    = array.new<int>()
var label myLabel       = label.new(na, na, '', color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_center)

if timeframe.change('D')
    array.unshift(startTimes, time)

if barstate.islast
    t = array.get(startTimes, n)
    label.set_xy(myLabel, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(myLabel, str.format('StartTime {0} trading days ago was {1}', n, str.format_time(t,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm')))
```

**Edit 1**
In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060214/start-of-x-days-prior/75064449?noredirect=1#comment132467806_75064449)
Answers to the questions have been put into the code as comments.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

// Timezone list can be found at https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/time-zone-names/
TZ0 = "Europe/Brussels", TZ1 = "Africa/Nairobi", TZ2 = "Asia/Thimbu"
ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

// Chart timezone cannot be detected (yet), so we'll need an input for that.
var string  tz  = input.string(TZ0, 'TimeZone', options=[TZ0,TZ1,TZ2])
var int     n   = input.int(2, 'Show startTime for this many trading days ago', 0)

var int[] startTimes    = array.new<int>()
var int[] endTimes      = array.new<int>()
var label myLabel       = label.new(na, na, '', color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_center)

f_formatTime(_timestamp) => str.format_time(_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', tz)

if timeframe.change('D')
    array.unshift(startTimes, time)
    // We can't get the end time of the current day, because it can't be known on beforehand due to trading days with reduced hours.
    // So we work around that by taking the closing time of the last bar of the previous session, and adding 1 day to it.
    array.unshift(endTimes, time_close[1] + ONE_DAY) 

if barstate.islast
    ts = array.get(startTimes, n)
    te = array.get(endTimes, n)
    label.set_xy(myLabel, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(myLabel, str.format('{0} trading days ago\nStartTime = {1}\nEndTime = {2}\nTimezone = {3}', n, f_formatTime(ts) , f_formatTime(te), tz))
```

**Edit 2**
In response to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75060214/start-of-x-days-prior/75064449?noredirect=1#comment132489846_75064449)
Indeed there seems to be an anomaly when using certain timeframes.
Solved by using [session.isfirstbar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Disfirstbar) and [session.islastbar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Dislastbar). Those will change depending on whether your chart is in RTH (Regular Trading Hours) or ETH (Extended Trading Hours).
If you want to use only RTH hours, even when your chart is in ETH, you can use [session.isfirstbar_regular](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Disfirstbar_regular) and [session.islastbar_regular](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Dislastbar_regular).

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

// Timezone list can be found at https://www.tradingcode.net/tradingview/time-zone-names/
TZ0 = "Europe/Brussels", TZ1 = "Africa/Nairobi", TZ2 = "Asia/Thimbu", TZ3 = "America/New_York"
ONE_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000

// Chart timezone cannot be detected (yet), so we'll need an input for that.
var string  tz  = input.string(TZ0, 'TimeZone', options=[TZ0,TZ1,TZ2,TZ3])
var int     n   = input.int(2, 'Show startTime for this many trading days ago', 0)

var int[] startTimes    = array.new<int>()
var int[] endTimes      = array.new<int>()
var label myLabel       = label.new(na, na, '', color=color.white, textcolor=color.black, style=label.style_label_center)

f_formatTime(_timestamp) => str.format_time(_timestamp, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm', tz)

if session.isfirstbar
    array.unshift(startTimes, time)
else if session.islastbar
    // If we're on the last bar, we're at the end of that day. Record the closing time of that bar.
    array.unshift(endTimes, time_close)

if barstate.islast
    ts = array.get(startTimes, n)
    te = array.get(endTimes, n)
    label.set_xy(myLabel, bar_index, high)
    label.set_text(myLabel, str.format('{0} trading days ago\nStartTime = {1}\nEndTime = {2}\nTimezone = {3}', n, f_formatTime(ts) , f_formatTime(te), tz))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, THANK YOU! Marked as the answer. Two follow-up questions if you don't mind.. 1) on futures - like ES1! - it shows the start time in the exchange's timezone. How can I show it in my timezone? (I'm ok with an user input of timezone if pinescript is unable to detect the timezone from the chart - unsure if this was implemented in recent times) 2) Is there a way to get the endTime as well? isLastBar/IsLastBar_Regular won't show for periods that hasn't ended yet, wondering if this logic can be leveraged to detect that.

Comment: Added Edit 1 section to my answer.

Comment: #GOAT! Thank you. Also, liked "(yet)" part, gives me hope.

Comment: I'm seeing something strange after adding <TZ3 = "America/New_York"> to the study/input option. Today, 01/10, when I'm viewing SPY on 3 minutes timeframe and have <n> input = 1, it plots start time = 01/09 9:30 AM (Mon) and end time = 01/07 4:00 PM (Sat), instead of 01/09 4:00 PM. When I increment the n by 1, it shows proper time for 01/06 (Fri). Would you be able to review this to see how to resolve it?

Comment: Added Edit 2 section to my answer.

Comment: Hmm, something seems even stranger with the 3rd version. When viewing SPY, 3 minute timeframe, RTH, NY TimeZone, and n = 2, it shows correct start time (01/09 9:30 AM), but end time is again 01/06 4:00 PM.  When I view it in ETH, the start time = 01/09 7:00 AM, but end time = 2022-12-27 8:00 PM. Also, would the inconsistency with session.islastbar/session.islastbar_regular cause any issue based on the remark listed on their doc ("This variable is not guaranteed to return true...")?